# "C:\Users\root\Desktop\%%I" add variable folders to command

Tags: image, file, batch-file, video, directory

I've got a simple [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) I created using the FrameShots software to grab images from multiple video files.

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('dir *.mp4 *.mkv /b /s') DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpeg "C:\Users\me\Videos\%%I" "C:\Users\me\Images"
```

It works great to grab images from each video file I have in my Videos folder, but I cannot get it to access the videos in the subfolders in the Videos folder (which is what I thought `/s` should achieve).

I hoped putting `/s` in the command would force FrameShots to check not only the video files in the Videos folder, but also the videos in the additional folders inside the videos folder (ie; vacation folder, work folder, kids folder...) but I was wrong.

It's a very basic bat file:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('dir *.mp4 *.mkv /b /s') DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpeg "C:\Users\me\Videos\%%I" "C:\Users\me\Images"
```

I was expecting to get 10 jpeg images from every video in the 'Videos' folder, including the subfolders, but I am currently getting images only from the mp4/mkv files that are not in subfolders but I want to get images from every mp4/mkv file in the 'Videos' folder, including all the subfolders.

Comment: Solved, thank you Mr. Personick!

Comment: If an answer solves your question please click the green check mark next to it; read [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn why this is important; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does the trick for you:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir "%UserProfile%\*.mp4" "%UserProfile%\*.mkv" /b /s') DO "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FrameShots\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpeg "%%I" "%USERPROFILE%\Images"
```

Using `DIR` with /S will recurse subdirectories, but the output will be the full path of the File matched, not a relative path, or a filename.

Therefore we can ignore the portion where you already filled in some file path.

Further since I know you want to search under your user profile I changed to using the Windows Variable for that and used it to explicitly make sure the search is carried out in the correct location, and I used that for the output as well to make sure that all of the photos are generated in your images folder.

So now this will run on anyone's computer that has this program installed, not just your specifically. :)

Comment: I made just a few minor changes to your script and it now works perfectly for me: FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir *.mp4 *.mkv /b /s') DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpg %%I "D:\Images"       Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all files in a directory (including subfolders) `for /r` is the way to go:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Video\Directory"
set "frame=C:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots"
set "me=C:\Users\me"

for /r "%dir%" %%A in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do (
    "%frame%\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpeg "%%A" "%me%\Images"

)
```

I set more variables than necessary to make it easier to read in the code block - you can set fewer/none if you like the full paths in the loop. `for /r` will loop through all .mp4 and .mkv files in your video directory (`dir`), set each as parameter `%%A`, and then use that parameter in your `frameshots.exe` command line. No need for looping through the output of `dir` required.

I'm not familiar with FrameShots so I just based my syntax on the examples you gave in your question and how I'm guessing they need to be corrected - essentially the line will be read like this when the loop iterates:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots\frameshots.exe" -count 10 -filetype .jpeg C:\Full\Path\Of\Video\File.extension" "C:\Users\me\Images"
```

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)